# Web API to Google Cloud Pub Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to google cloud technologies.
If I have a streaming web API online where I want to access JSON data from and write it into Cloud Pub/Sub, Do I need to create a python app engine or something that reads that Web API and writes the data into Cloud Pub/Sub or is there an easier way? 
Basically just poling a web API and getting JSON data.

Comment: You can directly steam your json data into Cloud Pub/Sub, no need to create anything extra to read the Web API and writes the data.

Comment: @JL-HN How so? Like this sample? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways that this could be achieved:

**Cloud Function**: With the help of [triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/), you could have the cloud function grab the data and write it to pub/sub using its [API Service](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview). Cloud functions uses a Nodejs runtime so you will need to use javascript to code the function.

**Direct Stream**: You can altogether skip the extra work and simply adapt your web service to use the Pub/Sub API service and write the data directly to it.

You can look into the [Pub/Sub Client API Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.16.x/) which offer sample and guidance on how to properly use the API.

Hope this is helpful.